# Not able to access Website using ip address, DNS working fine

Tags: .htaccess, url, ip, http-status-code-404, server-side

I'm having an issue when trying to access a web site by using its IP address. It throws a 404 error.

This is the IP:

```
http://72.167.164.203/
```

It works perfectly fine when accessing through domain name:

```
http://www.rocketbanner.com/
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

In the vhost config for the `www.rocketbanner.com` domain, add a server alias for the IP address:

```
ServerAlias 72.167.164.203
```

Otherwise, if the `72.167.164.203` "name" isn't associated with a vhost, it ends up being handled by a default vhost which may not be the one serving `www.rocketbanner.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Could be because of `name-based virtual hosting`. Using this multiple hosts can share the same IP address. For more detail information check [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html)